# How to set up Authentication flow in flutter like in react native

Tags: flutter

In React Native Navigation we have authentication flow like if user is signed in render authentication stack else show authenticated Stack like Below

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
);
```

How to achieve something like this in flutter